# create a mongoDB connection in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, eloquent

I was making a logIn controller in which I want to create a new mongo connection having a method in a model findByEmail

logInController.php

```
public function __construct()
    {
        // Creates mongo connection
        $this->collection = ((new MongoDBClient())->__get(env('MONGODB_DATABASE'))->users);

    }
```

model: Users.php

```
 class Users extends Eloquent
    {
        protected $connection = 'mongodb';
        protected $collection = 'users';
        protected $attributes = [
            'status' => 1
        ];
    
        public function findByEmail($email)
        {
            $record = $this->where('email', $email)
                        ->first();
            return $record;
        }
    
       }
```

Please guide me how to create a connection using this. I know one way to create connection that is with the help of mongoDB client but I want to learn a new way to do it. Please help